# Kafka Connect: How can I send protobuf data from Kafka topics to HDFS using hdfs sink connector?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a producer that's producing protobuf messages to a topic. I have a consumer application which deserializes the protobuf messages. But hdfs sink connector picks up messages from the Kafka topics directly. What would the key and value converter in `etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties` be set to? What's the best way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

Kafka Connect is designed to separate the concern of serialization format in Kafka from individual connectors with the concept of [converters](http://docs.confluent.io/3.1.1/connect/concepts.html#converters). As you seem to have found, you'll need to adjust the `key.converter` and `value.converter` classes to implementations that support protobufs. These classes are commonly implemented as a normal Kafka Deserializer followed by a step which performs a conversion from serialization-specific runtime formats (e.g. Message in protobufs) to Kafka Connect's runtime API (which doesn't have any associated serialization format -- it's just a set of Java types and a class to define Schemas).

I'm not aware of an existing implementation. The main challenge in implementing this is that protobufs is self-describing (i.e. you can deserialize it without access to the original schema), but since its fields are simply integer IDs, you probably wouldn't get useful schema information without either a) requiring that the specific schema is available to the converter, e.g. via config (which makes migrating schemas more complicated) or b) a schema registry service + wrapper format for your data that allows you to look up the schema dynamically.

Comment: I have an implementation that is barely working.  I extended `Deserializer` of the `AvroConter` class using `avro-protobuf`.   I understand that Kafka Connect wants to limit the number of supported formats, namely JSON and Avro, so I'm not going to publish it as-is.  Then again, I don't want to copy and rename entire `avro-converter` to `protobuf-converter`.  What's the best approach to contribute the project?

Comment: Kafka Connect absolutely does not want to limit the number of supported formats. Quite the opposite, we included Converters and made the data API for connectors generic to support plugging in different serialization formats. A protobuf implementation would absolutely be valuable and I'd recommend publishing it.

We'd be open to including it in our repository alongside the AvroConverter, though we'd want to get a fairly complete implementation. The biggest issue I see is that to get a useful implementation, I'd expect that you need something similar to the schema registry.